# Why does the below recursive main function start with the value 1 as parameter?

Tags: c

So when I execute the code below in gcc :

```
int main (int n)
{
   if (n==5) return 0;
   else
   {
      printf ("%d ",n);
      main (n+1);
   }
}
```

it produces the output `1 2 3 4` instead of (what I unreasonably expected) `0 1 2 3 4` or something different, because `n` is not initialized anywhere. How does the compiler decide whether `n` is 1 or not?

Comment: Check the formal definition of what `main` should look like in C. The first argument is `argc` the number of arguments provided to the program *including* the program itself. Therefore it is always at least `1`. Thus, no `0` print in your code. Further if you provide some useless arguments (`main foo bar`) from your command line, you'll see even more iterations removed.. And just for kicks, try passing *five* arguments: `main 1 2 3 4 5` and see what happens. Better still, think about what will happen before doing it, then try it and see if you were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the default, the first parameter for the main function is the number of arguments, one of which is always the name of the program. So, when you execute your program, n (which equals to argc) is equal to 1, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* do something here */
}
```

Comment: Suppose it is `abc.c` so is the first argument `abc.c` ? Am I right?